# spring rabbitmq jsf interoperation issue

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have a JSF backing bean and spring+rabbitMQ app. And I call there

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(<send to the main queue - not first which I mentioned below>)
```

I can`t use there convertSendAndReceive because of complicated logic, chains of queues, etc. The issue is I have one output queue and its listener. This listener acts as a router, dispatching requests between queues, calls functions, etc

But I need to return to the customer "OK" string in case it has been processed on the first queue. This message then will go further to the next queue, but after first one I need to inform my customer with "OK" message. In other words sth like

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend
while(<wait for sth>){
    if(message comes){
      //send "OK" to customer back
      //I would listen here for my output queue, but I already have     a listener, how I can be sure that my message will come to my listener here, not there?

    } 
}
```

So the question is  - how to ack my JSF bean that my message has passed first queue and send back the response?

Answer (score 0):

The `RabbitTemplate` has option like `setConfirmCallback`. With that you should supply one more parameter for `convertAndSend` with `CorrelationData` and `correlate` from the

```
void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause);
```

implementation to wait before sending `OK` response.

Comment: Thank you Artem, but the issue is I don`t have a channel there, I just have JSF bean and no rabbit stuff. I have an access only to rabbit template. Thank you

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you mean regarding `channel`. `ConfirmCallback` is an inner interface in the `RabbitTemplate`.

Comment: I`m really sorry, I mixed up two pages in my browser. Thank you again,Artem, I just have done as you said, but the issue is rabbit template allows only one confirm callback, but I will have a hundred of jsf pages. I understand, I can create any logic for that but it still not quite clear for me, I mean concept. In other words, I send the message from one point of my code to queue1 but need to receive an answer in another point of code from queue2, so I just need to check correlationId in confirm method and make a decision there? Is there any more simple way to do it? Thank you

Comment: Isn't `sendAndReceive` appropriate for you?

Comment: I'm not sure, because if my listener gets a message, it will send it further and should send back it to other queue for replies the same time, reply queue may change during execution, I have tried sendAndReceive but always get null even with corrId and replyTo, I'm just stuck with it

Comment: now I had to set up listener for 'reply' queue and put correlationIds to concurrenthashmap and check them when message comes to it